# Songs bought from the Ubuntu One Music store showing Unknown Album/Artist in streaming app

Tags: ubuntu-one, streaming, mp3-tag

I've been using Ubuntu one for several years and have purchased several albums from the Ubuntu One music store.  All was well while I was playing them from Rhythmbox or Banshee.  However, I recently started using the U.O. streaming android app and streaming section of the one.ubuntu.com website and most of my music appears to be untagged.  What is going on?  Before this question is dismissed as a duplicate, let me reiterate the crucial differences:

- ALL of the music in my U.O. account was bought in the Ubuntu One music store.  This is NOT music that I ripped or bought elsewhere
- The mp3s that end up on my hard drive DO appear to be tagged correctly
- The issue affects the U.O. Streaming Music Android app AND the website (viewed in Chrome on my Win7 work PC)

Is this some problem with the streaming service?  Is there anything I can do?

Comment: The service is obsolete